# Extensive nested IF, ISNUMBER, MATCH

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, if

```
=
IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A26;B$14#;0));A26;
IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A$36;B$14#;0));IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A$36;B$26:B26;0));

IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A$37;B$14#;0));IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A$37;B$26:B26;0));

IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A$38;B$14#;0));IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A$38;B$26:B26;0));

IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A$39;B$14#;0));IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A$39;B$26:B26;0));
0;A$39);A$38);A$37);A$36))))))
```

With this nested if(and more) I'm essentially trying to see if the first number input (A26) is within a list (B$14#). If it's not in that list, I want to replace it with one of the "filler" numbers (A$36, A$37, A$38, A$39)

But as we go down the list, I dont want to reuse the filler numbers. A$36 should only be used once, so it should check within the **new list** being created if it has already been used. ISNUMBER(MATCH(A$36;**B$26:B26**;0))

And if it exists within that list, it should move on to the next "filler number" A$37 and so forth. Right now this formula will work on all the initial numbers (A26) if they're in the list but will return "FALSE" when it's supposed to take from the filler numbers.

Is it simply a matter of me having misplaced my parenthesis?

Comment: It would be helpful to see some sample data and the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are doing the opposite of what you want to do. To work as desired, the formula should be:

```
=IF(NOT(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A26,B$14#,0))), A26,
 IF(NOT(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A$36,B$14#,0))),A$36,
 IF(NOT(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A$37,B$14#,0))),A$37,
 IF(NOT(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A$38,B$14#,0))),A$38,
 IF(NOT(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A$39,B$14#,0))),A$39,0)))))
```

The basic test you made was checking for `MATCH()` having a numerical result which would indicate the number exists in B14#. If so, you wanted to move on to testing for the placeholders. But you were not:  your result for success was to use the number in A26 but... success = "number IS in the list and so should NOT be the result"... unfortunately. I have made the modification of wrapping `NOT()` around the test so the result is reversed. Now TRUE means it is NOT in the list, so TRUE's result can be the A26 value. And similarly then for the follow-on testing.

Line 1: Tests whether A26 is present in B14# or not; returns A26 if not.
Line 2: Tests whether A36 is present in B14# or not; returns A36 if not.
Line 3, and so on: Same test for each of the other placeholders in order. Stops at the first successful (not present) placeholder and returns it.

And finally, if the A26 value and all placeholders are in the list, it returns 0 (as it looks like you desire).

I usually try to use as close as possible to a person's work if the work is involved or almost successful figuring it fits their preferences and experience better than a big set of changes.

This however, had the already mentioned problem, but also another. Notice that where you had two `IF()` tests per line, you'll see I only have one. Your approach essentially had each line saying `If this test is TRUE then if this test is TRUE` which quite complicated matters along with the using of results in the opposite way from what was needed. The extra `IF()` clause in each line had to go.

However, if you are willing to change approaches, a slight change would be clearer to understand and therefore maintain. A second slight change should make it much easier to understand and therefore maintain.

You can use `ISERROR()` in place of `NOT(ISNUMBER())`. That is more direct and as a single function, easier to follow.

The second change would be to shift from `IF()` to `IFS()`. It is much clearer for laying out a long list of conditions. Each can go on a single line and so it clearer how to add conditions and since they don't seem to mix into each other, it's each one's full meaning and use is clearer. You can use something like 127 conditions while you can only nest something like 64 `IF()`'s. It would look like:

```
=IFS(ISERROR(MATCH(A26,B$14#,0)),A26,
     ISERROR(MATCH(A36,B$14#,0)),A36,
     ISERROR(MATCH(A37,B$14#,0)),A37,
     ISERROR(MATCH(A38,B$14#,0)),A38,
     ISERROR(MATCH(A39,B$14#,0)),A39,
     TRUE,0)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).